# How to get portable link to Doxygen generated section "Examples"?

Tags: hyperlink, doxygen

When examples are included in the generated docs (via `@example` tag) they are all collected by Doxygen in a list in the generated docs in the section "Examples". In the documentation one can then easily refer to the individual examples via `@ref example1.c "example1.c"`

This works well.

However, I would like to include a link to the auto-generated section "Examples" (not any of the individual examples) and since its generated I cannot add a section tag that I could later refer to.

Since the generated examples section file is always named **`examples.html`** by Doxygen it is of course easy to "cheat" and just insert a markdown link `[Examples](examples.html)`. This, again, works fine for the HTML doc. But, for obvious reason this does not work in the PDF version.

What is the portable way of referring to the "Examples" section that works for all output formats (that I obviously overlook)?

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? I don't think this is possible but you could probably use the `\htmlonly`  / `\latexonly` etc commands to make an explicit reference (best is to pack the relevant code in an `ALIASES` setting so it is a bit more potable.

Comment: I'm using the latest v1.9.3 but I don't believe this to be version dependent. I can see that the "examples.tex" have a "\doxysection{Examples}"  but that macro does not have a "\label{}" so it cannot be referenced. So my guess is that it is, as you say, not possible (without augmenting "examples.tex" and do a manual \latexonly ref)

Comment: No this problem is not version dependent. I think best is to create an enhancement issue in the doxygen issue tracker on github.